# changing numbers in some lines of notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to change the xyz data of my input file which is written in the following order:

```
8455 529 8 -0.141000 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
```

the last three numbers are xyz.

But every time something goes wrong. At first, the CR LF would go between the numbers and change the values. Then I tried to handle them, but it seems some lines are deleted.

I want to do this:

I have 9600 lines like the above_mentiones lines in notepad++ which I want to change the last three number with some other numbers from a different file. How should I do that which these lines and also other lines in the notepad++ file would not be affected?

Comment: Do you know how to program? I'd probably tackle this with a small custom script (either Javascript or Python)

Comment: I am really new to python, but I think with a little more explanation I can.

Comment: Well the idea would be to open the file that contains your coordinates, iterate over each line (using a for loop for example) and take each line and split it using the space character as a split delimiter. This will give you a list of 7 values where the last 3 are xyz respectively. I would then take the line again and use the language's String replace function to replace each X,Y,Z value accordingly. This explanation is mostly algorithmical though, I'm not familiar with Python to tell you exactly which commands to run.

Comment: I can barely understand the concept but thank you for that. If anybody can say what should I do with python please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood you right and I have no idea how to do something like that in notepad++, but i recommend to use the tool [q](http://harelba.github.io/q/) to perform SQL selects on Text Files.

If your file1 looks like

```
a e f g
a e f g
8455 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215 
8456 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215 
8457 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215 
8458 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215 
8459 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215 
8460 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
```

and your file 2 looks like

```
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
8455 529 8 -0.000000 24.000000 8.000000 16.000000 
8456 529 8 -0.000000 24.000000 8.000000 16.000000 
8457 529 8 -0.000000 24.000000 8.000000 16.000000 
8458 529 8 -0.000000 24.000000 8.000000 16.000000 
8459 529 8 -0.000000 24.000000 8.000000 16.000000 
8460 529 8 -0.000000 24.000000 8.000000 16.000000
```

you can use

```
q.py -H "SELECT file02.a, file02.b, file02.c, file02.d, file01.e, file01.f, file01.g from ..\q\01.txt file01 JOIN ..\q\02.txt file02 ON file01.a=file02.a">03.txt
```

to get

```
a b c d e f g
8455 529 8 -0.000000 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
8456 529 8 -0.000000 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
8457 529 8 -0.000000 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
8458 529 8 -0.000000 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
8459 529 8 -0.000000 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
8460 529 8 -0.000000 24.508381 8.604702 16.976215
```

The double Header is a trick to force q to treat the Values as string - maybe there is a parameter I do not know.